# Best way to access Google Cloud Endpoint APIs from Angular2 typescript app?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-endpoints, google-api-js-client

Should I be using [gapi and the JavaScript Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js) to interact with the Google Cloud Endpoint APIs I create? Or can you use the [HTTP Client/Library in Angular2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#) to do all your requests to the API? The APIs will have authorization and authenticating features. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about the Angular2 Library, but using the JavaScript Client Library brings a lot of advantages (like avoid dealing with XMLHttpRequests, etc..) and you just have to manipulate JS Objects. The Promises version allows very clean code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found HTTPclient library in Angular2 more convenient and better with examples and docs.

Comment: Can you outline your solution? I'm also trying to do this.